# How to use entity framework migrations with multiple dbcontexts mapping different domain classes to the same table

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I want to use a DDD approach to create my domain model. I understood that in a bounded context, only the data that is needed for that context, should be available, using the ubiquitous language of that context.

Lets say I have a `Buyer` class in the namespace `BuyerContext` and a `Seller` class in the namespace `SellerContext`. In the end both domain classes should be mapped to the `Users` table of the database. **I use EF Core 2.1 for that.**

One domain class may have fields/properties that are not part of the other domain class, like `Buyer.CreditCardNumber` or `Seller.Rating`.

To leverage the DDD approach I create two dbcontexts for each bounded context, like `BuyerDbContext` and `SellerDbContext`, and configure EF to use the same `Users` table, but only mapping those fields neccessary for the bounded context. I know how to do that, I also read about creating a project for each dbcontext.

**What I dont know is**, what I need to do, to use migrations with this setup, so when the database will be initialized or migrated, it creates a `User` table with a field `CreditCardNumber` (configured in `BuyerDbContext`) and a field `Rating` (configured in `SellerDbContext`).

**The only solution I found** is to create another model that kind of represents the complete database with its own dbcontext like `EntitiesDbContext`, and use that context for migrations. So I end up with a class `User` with two fields `CreditCardNumber` and `Rating`. I read that I might need to disable some kind of "Initialization" on the other dbcontexts.

**Is this the right approach?**

Comment: The first thing you should ask yourself is: Are Buyers and Sellers really a different bounded contexts? Typically I would say, because they usually belong together. The bounded context is typically something like "Sales" or "Marketing", "Logistics". Without knowing a lot of the contexts and the domain its hard for people go give you any kind of answers. Buyer and Seller just sound like Entities or Aggregates in your domain, not necessary a bounded context

Comment: Adding to @Tseng's comment, if Buyer and Sellers are, in fact, in different bounded context, then they should be stored in different databases (or schemas, or at least tables). There should be minimum coupling between bounded contexts and sharing a table completely defeats the purpose of splitting a domain in BCs. On the other hand, as Tseng mentions, it's very unlikely that buyers and sellers belong to different BCs as they are both necessary in many contexts: a buyer buys from a seller, a seller delivers goods to a buyer, a seller sends promotions to a buyer, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only solution I found is to create another model that kind of represents the complete database
>
> Is this the right approach?

Yes.  It's that or simply don't use Migrations and manage the database schema with some other tool.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'm not a fanboy of migrations since I dont think it's the applications responsibility to cater for the database. If possible I use SSDT primarely for database solutions but it depends on your project of course if it's possible to deploy SSDT-packages or not but normally it is.

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/ssdt/

Comment: Yes, I might not use migrations in production, but its a great tool for development. Thanks for the ssdt hint, I will give that a try